# Alpha mask with PHP/GD?

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible to mask an image using another image's alpha in PHP/GD so that the result is 24bit png?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php#94986

Comment: well one image would be jpg, the mask image would be png24 and the result would be a png24 made from RGB of the jpg image and alpha from the mask image.

Comment: Well, either try and adapt the function in the link I posted above to your needs, if it were me, I would probably use [ImageMagick where possible](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/#masks).

Comment: Thanks, the function works great, now my CMS can generate proper rounded thumbnails with shadows. Imagine that, no more boring square thumbnails! You should really post that link as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by processing the image pixel-by-pixel manually (using [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) and [imagesetpixel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php)).

If the image is relatively small (i.e. anything you'd call an icon) and doesn't change too often (so you can cache the result), GD will do just fine. I've used this method to generate gray versions for disabled button 64x64 icons which rarely ever change.

If you need to do this with larger images and more frequently, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) will do any image manipulation you'd ever want. It can do the [masking](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/) you are looking for.